# Github actions only on first push

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm working on a github action that creates an app on ArgoCD. The problem is that I want to execute it only once, the first time that it gets push with the k8s yamls.
Is there any way to restrict the github action to the first push on the repo?
I have been looking to the github triggers, but I was not able to find any relation.

This is a sample of the action:

```
on: push
name: deploy-argo-app
jobs:
  deploy-argo-app:
    name: Deploy new app on ArgoCD
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    - name: Install Argo Cli
      run: |
          VERSION=$(curl --silent "https://api.github.com/repos/argoproj/argo-cd/releases/latest" | grep '"tag_name"' | sed -E 's/.*"([^"]+)".*/\1/')
          sudo curl -sSL -o /usr/local/bin/argocd https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/releases/download/$VERSION/argocd-linux-amd64
          sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/argocd
    - name: Create app
      run: | 
          argocd app create guestbook --repo https://github.com/argoproj/argocd-example-apps.git --path guestbook --dest-server https://kubernetes.default.svc --dest-namespace default
```

Comment: This is not the way to use push, but if you can use a pull_request event, I think it is the most reliable way to use `open` in the pull_request types.
Ref: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request

Answer (score 3):

I found kind of a workaround.

```
on: push
name: deploy
jobs:
  deploy:
    if: github.run_number == 1
```

Basically "github.run_number" gives you the push number. It will work only on the first push and then it will be ignore.

Answer (score 2):

I have been looking for something similar, but I needed to know the first push on any given branch.

First, you can see everything available to you on your Github context by [running this worfklow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#context-availability):

```
      - name: Dump GitHub context
        id: github_context_step
        run: echo '${{ toJSON(github) }}'
```

I was able to see that on the first push to any branch the

`github.event.before = 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

and

`github.event.created = true`

whereas for any subsequent push to that same branch the github.event.before will give a numerical reference to the previous commit, and the github.event.created will be false.

Slightly related, but maybe still useful for people who find themselves on the same hunt I was on!